# HERE maps adjust truck profile

Tags: here-api

Is there a documentation that describes how I can change the truck speed/general profile?

I understand, I can add information to my request, e.g., 'fastest;truck;traffic:enabled&limitedWeight=...&width=...&length=...'

But I couldn't find a documentation regarding changing the speed profile of a truck. Also it would come in handy if this profile would be a xml file that I can adjust and connect to my request.

Comment: Could you let us know what API you are using?

Comment: sure, sorry. I use the REST api. In particular Routing API v8.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Routing API V8, there is no dedicated parameter to change the speed profile of a truck routing. The internal speed profile is calculated based on the truck's gross weight parameter, e.g., truck[grossWeight]=4500.

Based on the weight, one of the following speed profile will be selected.
Light: weight <= 7.5t
Medium: 7.5t < weight <= 18t
Heavy: 18t < weight